# Using concordance in Python NLTK to return the value for a found key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I would like to use concordance to find instances of words or phrases in text and then look for the found word/phrase in a dictionary and return the corresponding value. Here is the code I have so far.

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk, re, pprint
OutFileName = "shark_uri.txt"
OutFile = open(OutFileName, 'w')
book1 = open('shark_test.txt', 'rU').read() 
token1 = nltk.word_tokenize(book1)
text1 = nltk.Text(token1)
LineNumber = 0
for k, v in bio_dict.iteritems(): 
        text1.concordance(k)
    #if k is found then print v, else go on to next k
    if k #is found:
        OutFile.write(v)
        OutFile.write('\n')
        LineNumber += 1
    else
        LineNumber += 1
OutFile.close()
```

This code should be reading a paragraph about a shark in the shark_test.txt file. The bio_dict contains key value pairs like this

```
'ovoviviparous':'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ovoviviparity', 
'predator':'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Predation',
```

The key represents a word or phrase the program is looking for. The value is the DBpedia URI that corresponds to the word/phrase. The idea is that when a word like "predator" is found in the text, the program would return the DBpedia URI for Predation.
I have been getting lots of weird results and I think it is because I need to tell the program that if k is found to return v else go to the next k. I have put a placeholder for this in the code block above. I don't quite know how to phrase this in Python. Would it be something like if k == True? 
Without this conditional it appears to just be going through the dictionary printing all the values regardless of whether or not the key is found. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is working now is that you are iterating over all key, value pairs in the `bio_dict` dictionary and then using `concordance` to print the lines of `text1` where `k` exists. Important to note here is that using `concordance` **does not return anything**, rather it just *prints*. So even if you tried to use the return value (which you don't actually in your code), you cannot. When you write `if k:`, this will always be `True` - assuming your keys are nonempty strings (none of the keys evaluate to `False`).

If I understand your problem correctly, you really shouldn't use `concordance` at all. Rather, do something like this:

```
for word in token1:                        # Go through every word in your text
    if word in bio_dict:                   # Check if the word is in the dict
        OutFile.write(bio_dict[word]+'\n') # Output the value to your file
```

Additionally, your `LineNumber` counter doesn't actually count what you want because you are reading the input file all at once and tokenizing the entire thing in `token1`. But since you don't actually use `LineNumber`, you can remove that variable and still get the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get what I needed with this bit of code.

```
from __future__ import division
import urllib
import re, pprint, time
in_file_name = "shark_id.txt"
in_file = open(in_file_name, 'r')
out_file_name = "shark_uri.txt"
out_file = open(out_file_name, 'w')

for line in in_file:                                                    
line = line.strip()                                             
address = 'http://eol.org/api/data_objects/1.0/' + line + '.xml'    
web_content = urllib.urlopen(address)                           
results = web_content.read().lower()                                        
temp_file_name = "Temp_file.xml"                                    
temp_file = open(temp_file_name, 'w')                               
temp_file.write(results)    
temp_file.close()                                           
print line
print len(results)              
temp_file = open('Temp_file.xml')
data = temp_file.read()
temp_file.close()
for k, v in bio_dict.iteritems():                           
    if k in data:                       
        out_file.write(line + ',')                                  
        out_file.write(k + ',')                                 
        out_file.write(v)                                       
        out_file.write('\n')                                        
time.sleep(.5)
in_file.close()                                                     
out_file.close()
```